# Linux Socket System call "accept" never returning?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, system

I'm running into a strange issue trying to test a simple socket program. When I call the "accept" function here, my program seems to hang... it prints out "SENPAI PLS" but never "SADDASSDA".

I was getting past this part of my code last night. For context, this is running on a large server with quite a few other students probably trying to do the same project as me, and I'm sure some of them are leaving their server programs running.

Could the service being busy or full cause accept to just never finish?

```
     do{  
        printf("SENPAI PLS\n");  
        clientFD=accept(serverFD, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clientAddressSize);  
        printf("SADDASSDA\n");  
        if(clientFD==-1){  
            sleep(1);  
        }  
    }while (clientFD==-1);
```

Comment: I assume you have some client program trying to connect to it. `accept` will block until a connection comes in. What's happening in your client?

Comment: The accept function itself has a loop until there's a connection attempted?

Comment: `accept` will not return until a connection is accepted (unless the listening socket is in nonblocking mode).

Comment: Okay great! That's all I needed to know, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accept` will not return until a connection is accepted (unless the listening socket is in nonblocking mode).